No Google Analytics code rendered in the header?
I'm using Customizr Wordpress theme.
I've pasted Google Analytics code into header.php, right before </head>.
However, when I load my web page, there is no Google Analytics code in the header. Google's test also says it isn't found.
I installed the cache cleaning plugin for Wordpress, but that didn't help.
The web is simple, I'm keeping plugins to a minimum; currently using only 2 plugins: Open Graph and Twitter Card Tags and RPB Chessboard.
Why aren't the changes to header.php visible?

Thanks @Danijel for providing the link to their github. I've played around with the theme and I found that you should make changes here https://github.com/presscustomizr/customizr/blob/dev/templates/head-no-model.php
It seems that the code from here https://github.com/presscustomizr/customizr/blob/dev/header.php#L10 is executed and doesn't reach to your added code.
I was able to see the GA script after adding the code in the mentioned file.

Works! Do you know the reason why anything after line 10 is not executed in header.php? It seems very unusual setup.

I think this line https://github.com/presscustomizr/customizr/blob/dev/core/init.php#L136 makes the if condition to be executed from the header.php, then will be executed this action https://github.com/presscustomizr/customizr/blob/dev/header.php#L16 and the next line will stop the rest of the execution

There can be various region for your changes not reflecting.

Can you see if there are multiple header.php file as headers-{NAME}.php. If yes then paste the gtag in all headers file.
Can you open your url by appending query parameters. Eg: site.com/?random=123. By doing this, it will fetch fresh content by disabling page cache.
There might be other caching like OPCache or Varnish cache running on your server.


Here is the source: https://github.com/presscustomizr/customizr.


There are no multiple headers. 2. Doesn't help. 3. Will check with the hosting provider.



There is no caching on server.


What else could be the reason?? Very unexpected behaviour...
